# deselect the checkbox using the listbox item in tkinter python and print the current item of listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, tkinter.checkbutton

I have two checkbox Pass and FAIL
I am parsing the csv for column1 and adding the two checkbox .

```
        X = 100
        Y = 71
        for item in column1[key]:
            if item != '':
                listbox.insert('end', item)
                chk_state1 = tk.IntVar()
                tk.Checkbutton(self.root, text="PASS",variable=chk_state1,font=("Arial Bold", 8),).place(x=X,y=Y)
                chk_state2 = tk.IntVar()
                tk.Checkbutton(self.root, text="FAIL",variable=chk_state2,font=("Arial Bold", 8),).place(x=X+80,y=Y)
                Y = Y +20
```

1. How to know which row of column1 Checkbox is selected
2. At a time only one checkbox should be selected

Any inputs will be helpful thanks in advance

Comment: For item 2, why don't you just use one checkbox for each item: checked for PASS, otherwise for FAIL.  Or use radiobuttons instead of checkboxes.  For item 1, suggest to use a dictionary to store those tkinter variables (`IntVar()`) and use `item` as the key.

Comment: Does not understood can you elaborate more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For item 1, use a dictionary (item names as the keys) to hold the created tkinter `IntVar`s. Then you can get the checked state for each item by going through the dictionary later.

For item 2, you can use `Radiobutton` instead of `Checkbutton`.

```py
        X = 100
        Y = 71

        myfont = ('Arial Bold', 8)
        self.cblist = {}
        for item in column1[key]:
            if item != '':
                listbox.insert('end', item)
                chk_state = tk.IntVar(value=0)
                tk.Radiobutton(self.root, text='PASS', variable=chk_state, value=1, font=myfont).place(x=X, y=Y)
                tk.Radiobutton(self.root, text='FAIL', variable=chk_state, value=0, font=myfont).place(x=X+80, y=Y)
                self.cblist[item] = chk_state
                Y += 22

        tk.Button(self.root, text='Check', command=self.check).place(x=X, y=Y+10)

    ...

    def check(self):
        result = ('Fail', 'Pass')
        print(', '.join(f'{item}:{result[var.get()]}' for item, var in self.cblist.items()))
```

Note that I have added a button to print out the selected state for each item.

Comment: I tried this code , in print i am getting all items instead of particular items for that pass or fail row

Comment: @Piu The `check()` is just an example of getting the checked state for each item, you can modify it to filter out items, for example only show PASS items.